# RHEL - zenity: needing to use options with only one button and scrollbars at same time

Tags: zenity

I need to show a text and by using "zenity --text-info" I guess it is the best approach. But I don't realize why zenity thinks I would need two buttons just to show a paragraph <= Actually, I don't ! => Then I tried with "--warning" or "--info" options because they only show one button ... now my problen is when the paragraph is pretty long, those options don't show scrollbars. Is there a way using zenity to get "only one button" + "scrollbars" at the same time?

By now I'm using "--text-info" and "--cancel-label="" " to clear the unused button label ... but it is not stethic at all.

I'm running on RHEL 7.3.

Thanks in advance.